# Will the chrome.webRequest api for chrome extensions be deprecated soon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension, and am reading conflicting information regarding the webRequest Api, as to whether it will be deprecated or not. I am building a chrome extension that uses chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener() to read outgoing request headers before a request is sent, and to modify the request being sent based on some conditions, along with caching some of the request header values.

So my question is, if I submit a chrome extension using this api, and the method above, will I be allowed to submit it and have people freely download and use it, possibly even monetize it, and whether the webRequest api will be deprecated soon. Please only comment if you are 100 percent sure, I have read many contradictory stack overflow answers on similar questions.

The documentation seems very vague to me, and I specifically remember Google adding a orange coloured banner on https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/ warning that this api will be deprecated soon, which is now no longer there( I could be misremembering this).

Edit: I know there is declarativeNetRequest but it is not powerful enough for what I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not deprecated.

- **All ManifestV3 extensions can use webRequest API in a read-only way** i.e. you should remove `'blocking'` from addListener and remove webRequestBlocking from manifest.json.

  If you want to change the headers you'll have to keep using ManifestV2 (in general) or try making a set of rules prepared beforehand in declarativeNetRequest e.g. in some cases you can add the rule dynamically inside webRequest.onBeforeRequest listener so that the rule will have a chance to apply to the incoming headers.
- **[Force-installed](https://www.google.com/search?q=Force-installed%20extensions%20in%20Chrome) (via policies) ManifestV3 extensions can still use the `'blocking'` mode** and webRequestBlocking permission.